# How can i achieve below shown background color loader inside a cell in a table using html (Please check the image link for design ref)

Tags: html, css

[Table design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDmze.png)

Please help to achieve the background color loader inside a cell in a table using html as shown in the image. I tried to design by below way, but not working

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><div style="width:20%;background-color:blue;">12345</div></td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

But after giving width for div inside cell, text is also moving based on div width.
I need to place the values on the center of the cell and background color width should be increase or decrease based on my calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```css
table{
  border:1px lightgray solid;

}

.inside-div{
  position:relative;
  width:100px;
  height:20px;
}

.loader-div {
  height:100%;
  background:lightblue;
}
p{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: -25%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
     <div class='inside-div'>
       <div class='loader-div' style='width:45.5%;'></div>
       <p>45.5</p>
     </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

Comment: there is one correction. It is not possible make a td position as relative, it wont work. We should add a div inside the td and make that div position as relative.